# Altering add_to_cart_form_submit() and random PDOException while adding to cart

Tags: 7, commerce, database

I have created a customized product with lots of attributes to set for it.
I also altered hook_add_to_cart_form_submit() where I collect all selected attributes and calculate a new price based on the selected and configured attributes.
So in my

```
function MYMODULE_add_to_cart_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {}
```

I create a big array and:

```
if (empty($form_state['line_item']->line_item_id)) {
    if ($attributes)
        $form_state['line_item']->data['context']['attributes'] = $attributes;
    $line_item = commerce_product_line_item_new($product, $form_state['values']['quantity'], 0, $form_state['line_item']->data, $form_state['line_item']->type);
    //   ...
}
```

I'm not sure if I am doing it right, I just want to store that array in the line-item table.
While adding product to cart randomly I get:

```
"PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'commerce_line_item-177-0-0-und' for key 'PRIMARY': INSERT INTO {field_data_commerce_unit_price} ..."
```

error.
Should I use some special format for this $attribute array? Everything is stored as BLOB in commerce_line_item.data field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [commerce_product_line_item_new](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!commerce!modules!product_reference!commerce_product_reference.module/function/commerce_product_line_item_new/7), drupal is trying to insert an already existant record to the table `field_data_commerce_unit_price` which has it's primary key defined as :

> PRIMARY KEY (`entity_type`,`entity_id`,`deleted`,`delta`,`language`),

Since the product already exists, it fails with a constraint violation error :

> Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry

What you are trying to do could be accomplished by adding a new **cost** item to the current order based on the attributes you mention, not by modifying the current item price which I guess is what you are trying to do.

So IMHO, you may try to have a base price for your item (or even a 0 price) and once the customer adds it to cart, add another cost item with the charges calculated based on the attributes he sets.